# Javascript Calculation Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a HTML and Javascript calculation form for a school class. The current code I have allows the form to automatically calculate the total cost when you click the radio/check box's.  The problem is that I need to somehow make it so that either, 1. I can get some sort of real-time check if they user has selected the radio button/check box, or 2. Transform the code so that it needs a submit and reset button to make the validation and give the final cost. What I currently have is here:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <title>Holiday Calculation Form</title>
    <script src="form.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload='hideTotal()'>
    <div id="wrap">
        <form action="" id="holidayform" onsubmit="return false;">
        <div>
            <div class="headings">
               <fieldset>
                <legend>Island Hopper Cruises Fare Calculator</legend>
                <label >Complete the form below to calculate the cost of your cruise.</label>
                <label class='radiolabel'><br />
                  <br />
<br />
                 <input type="radio"  name="selectedbeach" value="Beach1" onclick="calculateTotal()"/>Main Beach - Azkaban Island ($49)</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedbeach" value="Beach2" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Main Beach - Amity Island ($79)</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedbeach" value="Beach3" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Main Beach - Treasure Island ($109)</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedbeach" value="Beach4" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Main Beach - Gilligan’s Island ($89)</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedbeach" value="Beach5" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Main Beach - Skull Island ($59)</label><br/>
                <br/>

                <br/>
                <p>
                <label for='twowayfare' class="inlinelabel">Two Way Fare</label>
               <input type="checkbox" id="twowayfare" name='twowayfare' onclick="calculateTotal()" />
               </p>
               <p>
                <input type="radio"  name="selectedseat" value="Flight1" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Economy Seat</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedseat" value="Flight2" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Business Class Seat</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedseat" value="Flight3" onclick="calculateTotal()" />First Class Seat</label><br/>

                <br/>
                </p>
                <div id="totalPrice"></div>

              </fieldset>
            </div>


            <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' onclick="calculateTotal()" />
        </div>  
       </form>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var holiday_cost = new Array();
 holiday_cost["Beach1"]=49;
 holiday_cost["Beach2"]=79;
 holiday_cost["Beach3"]=109;
 holiday_cost["Beach4"]=89;
 holiday_cost["Beach5"]=59;

 var fare_prices = new Array();
 fare_prices["Flight1"]=1;
 fare_prices["Flight2"]=1.5;
 fare_prices["Flight3"]=2.5;


function getHolidayPrice()
{  
    var HolidayPrice=1;

    var theForm = document.forms["holidayform"];

    var selectedBeach = theForm.elements["selectedbeach"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedBeach.length; i++)
    {

        if(selectedBeach[i].checked)
        {

            HolidayPrice = holiday_cost[selectedBeach[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }

    return HolidayPrice;
}



function twowayPrice()
{
    var twowayPrice=1;

    var theForm = document.forms["holidayform"];

    var includeTwoway = theForm.elements["twowayfare"];


    if(includeTwoway.checked==true)
    {
        twowayPrice=2;
    }

    return twowayPrice;
}

function getSeatPrice()
{  
    var SeatPrice=1;

    var theForm = document.forms["holidayform"];

    var selectedSeat = theForm.elements["selectedseat"];

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedSeat.length; i++)
    {

        if(selectedSeat[i].checked)
        {

            SeatPrice = fare_prices[selectedSeat[i].value];

            break;
        }
    }

    return SeatPrice;
}



function calculateTotal()
{
    //Here we get the total price by calling our function
    //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
    var flightPrice = getHolidayPrice() * twowayPrice() * getSeatPrice();

    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For the Holiday $"+flightPrice;

}

function hideTotal()
{
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='none';
}
```

Please Help!?,
Fonza

Comment: What problem are you having with this code?

Comment: don't do any action on click of radio, use your submit button for calculations. For validation, check for selected radio if not found then show some kind of error message. Where are you stuck?